# D3.js: Dynamically change the bar chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have been experimenting with D3.js quite a bit now and I have this bar chart that I have to refresh dynamically on a button click.

I have wrapped it up in a function, however, that does not seem to work.

What is the issue and how do I resolve it?

Code:

```
var margin = {top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 40},
    width = 900,
    height = 700;

var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

var tip = d3.tip()
  .attr('class', 'd3-tip')
  .offset([-10, 0])
  .html(function(d) {
    return "<strong>Popularity:</strong> <span style='color:teal'>" + d.popularity+"</span>";
  })

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

svg.call(tip);

function updateChart( concert){

d3.tsv(concert+".tsv", type, function(error, data) {
  x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));
  y.domain([0, 45]);
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
      .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
      .attr("y", 6)
      .attr("dy", "1em")
      .style("text-anchor", "end")
      .text("Popularity");

  var pops= svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")
      .attr("width", x)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.popularity> 30) {
           return "#010";
        else  
           return "000"; 
       })
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", height - 1)
      .attr("height", 1);

    pops.transition()
      .duration(1000)
      .delay(function (d, i) {
        return i * 100;
      })
      .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.popularity); })
      .attr("height", function(d) { return height- y(d.popularity); });

    pops.on('mouseover', tip.show)
      .on('mouseout', tip.hide);

  });

}

function type(d) {
  d.popularity= +d.popularity;
  return d;
}
```

I am calling it form my html file.
ex:

```
<button onclick="updateChart('JB')">JB</button>
```

Original Data:

```
month   popularity
January 24.6
February    26.2
March   28.4
April   30.9
May 32.9
June    32.4
July    30.7
August  30.1 
September   29.7
October 28.2
November    26.1
December    25
```

Updated:

```
month   popularity
January 73
February    72
March   70
April   69
May 62
June    57
July    64
August  66
September   72
October 77
November    78
December    77
```

Comment: I only see you've defined `.enter`, but you also need `.update` and `.exit` to handle updated data

Comment: How do i add them? @Fabricator

Comment: can you provide the original and updated data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see 2 problems at first glance :

- You are transitionning only on the `enter` selection :

```js
// pops only contains the 'enter selection' (=new elements)
var pops= svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)
    .enter().append("rect")

// So the transition will be only on the 'enter selection'
pops.transition()...
```

You should do it in two steps :

```
// pops now contains the 'update selection' (=existing elements)
  var pops= svg.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data);
// 'enter().append' creates elements but also add them automatically to the 'update selection'
  pops.enter().append("rect");

// Here attributes will apply on the 'enter + update selection' (=all elements)
  pops.attr("width", x)
      .attr("fill", function(d) {
        if (d.popularity> 30) {
           return "#010";
        else  
           return "000"; 
       })
      .attr("class", "bar")
      .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
      .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
      .attr("y", height - 1)
      .attr("height", 1);
```

- You are recreating the axis at every update

You should create them once, and juste update dynamic values in `updateChart`

At startup :

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .range([height, 0]);

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(x)
    .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
    .scale(y)
    .orient("left")
    .ticks(10)
    .tickFormat(d3.format("s"));

var gXAxis = svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "x axis")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
      .call(xAxis);

var gYAxis =  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "y axis")
      .call(yAxis);
```

At update :

```
// Update domains
x.domain(data.map(function(d) { return d.month; }));
y.domain([0, 45]);
// Update axis
gXAxis.call(xAxis);
gYAxis.call(yAxis);
// You could even handle it smoothly via a transition: 
// gXAxis.transition().call(xAxis);
// gYAxis.transition().call(yAxis);
```

Comment: Great! But how do I stop the recreating the x and y axes? 
If I remove the code for creating them and place them out of the function, they are misformed

Comment: check my update, I detailed a bit more what must be in update function

Comment: Thanks a lot! 
But one issue persists in my code, I am not able to figure it out. 
The color once set is not changed even if the values are... Why is this happening? I have attached the `fill` part within the update...

Comment: Can you update your code in your post ? I can only see this line : .attr("fill", "#010"). And you are using a static color, not depending on data

Comment: OK, check my update in the "You should do it in two steps :" part. Its related

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am new to D3 and this really made be understand quite a few things :)

Comment: you're welcome :) BTW you should read this : https://bost.ocks.org/mike/selection/

Answer (score -1):

First you need to set an ID when you input the data:

```
var pops= svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(data, function(d,i){ return d.month; // this value most be an Id for each node })
pops.enter().append("rect"); // newest nodes
update(); // updates nodes 
pops.exit().remove(); // remove exits nodes
```

Then you need to make a function when update all values for the viz

```
function update(){
   pops
    .attr("width", x)
    .attr("fill", "#010")
    .attr("class", "bar")
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.month); })
    .attr("width", x.rangeBand())
    .attr("y", height - 1)
    .attr("height", 1);
}
```

This is an example for understand the difference between entry and update of data. It is very important when you set the ".data(data, function(d,i){ return d.ID; })" given to d3 an ID for futures updates.